# Saving timestamp in mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

I have a field in a MySQL table which has a `timestamp` data type. I am saving data into that table. But when I pass the timestamp (`1299762201428`) to the record, it automatically saves the value `0000-00-00 00:00:00` into that table.

How can I store the timestamp in a MySQL table?

Here is my `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id,d_id,l_id,connection,s_time,upload_items_count,download_items_count,t_time,status)
VALUES (1,5,9,'2',1299762201428,5,10,20,'1'),
       (2,5,9,'2',1299762201428,5,10,20,'1')
```

Comment: **What timestamp** you're talking about? Where did you get it?

Comment: can u paste ur table structure here ?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

pass like this

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1299762201428')
```

Comment: but the value you get in db shows the column type is `datetime`, if you want to change it to `timestamp` then change the column type to `varchar(15)`

Comment: Then put it on an INT field. Anyway, a timestamp is only a representation of a date, and vice versa. You can convert from timestamp to date with the function jimy told you, and the other way with `strtotime`. edit: btw, timestamp only covers a range of all possible dates (1970-01-01 to xx-xx-2032 I think)

Comment: so what is the use of timestamp datatype? s_time field has timestamp datatype. Can't I save 1299762201428 to that field?

Comment: @lakum4stackof: For timestamp datatype, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html for detail.

Comment: @lakum, that is correct.  And you **should not** save a unix timestamp to the database.  The database has *real* datetime fields.

Comment: @lakum4stackof - the use of timestamp is that you do save the timestamp, but it is only displayed as a date. Internally (as all data types) it's stored as signed integer. If you also want to format that timestamp as an integer, I suggest that you just use INT field then. Use of timestamp column is the date manpipulation (adding intervals and such).

Answer (score 57):

Hey there, use the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function for this.

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
(id,d_id,l_id,connection,s_time,upload_items_count,download_items_count,t_time,status)
VALUES
(1,5,9,'2',FROM_UNIXTIME(1299762201428),5,10,20,'1'), 
(2,5,9,'2',FROM_UNIXTIME(1299762201428),5,10,20,'1')
```

Comment: Why is this better than `date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1299762201428')`?

Comment: Type safety: `FROM_UNIXTIME` yields a native mysql date type while php's `date()` returns a string.

Comment: It's better because web server ( PHP ) and MySQL could be in different places. So, date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1299762201428') will set the TimeZone of the web server. 

With different web servers placed in different zones you will have inconsistent data. Alternatively, in your code, you have to force the application timezone to the timezone of MySQL. [date_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 20):

```
$created_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(created_date)VALUES('$created_date')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 16):

Some things to clarify:

- MySQL timestamp field type doesn't store unix timestamps but rather a datetime-kind value.
- UNIX timestamp is a number of a regular int type.
- The timestamp you're talking about is not a regular unix timestamp but a timestamp with milliseconds.

therefore the correct answer would be

```
$timestamp = '1299762201428';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', substr($timestamp, 0, -3));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `now()` as well in your query, i.e. :

```sql
insert into table (time) values(now());
```

It will use the current timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

Datatype '**bigint unsigned**' may suit this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the field you are trying to save the value in is a datetime field **it's not but the same seems to be true for timestamps**. If so mysql expects the format to be Year-month-day Hour:minute:second. In order to save the timestamp you will have to convert the field to numeric using a query like

```
alter table <table_name> change <field> <field> bigint unsigned
```

If you are using the current time you can use now() or current_timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Note: 1299762201428 looks more like a millisecond-timestamp (like Date()*1 in JavaScript), and you probably have to divide that by 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Check field type in table just save time stamp value in datatype like  `bigint` etc.

Not `datetime` type

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
  $time = new DateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamp is the current time, you could use the mysql `NOW()` function

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime` field type. It comes with many advantages like human readability (nobody reads timestamps) and [MySQL functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

To convert from a unix timestamp, you can use MySQL function `FROM_UNIXTIME(1299762201428)`. To convert back you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t_time) FROM table_name`.

Of course, if you don't like MySQL function, you could always use PHP: `'INSERT INTO table_name SET t_time = ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix_timestamp)`.

Comment: The `timestamp` *field type* is human readable too (when using `SELECT` in the console). They are very different and both have their dis/advantages. The main difference is how time zones are being handled.

Comment: @Udo G: You are correct, but I still prefer `datetime` for various reasons. What is the biggest dis/advantage in your opinion?

Comment: biggest advantage for `timestamp`: it better matches the PHP timestamps as it is immune to time zone settings of both the server and the client, whereas `datetime` changes it's *displayed* value depending on the time zone of your MySQL client (of course it depends on your project, which one is better). biggest disadvantage for `timestamp`: it does not support NULL values and (I don't know what they did smoke when they programmed this) a `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL` field becomes a `TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. In my case I unfortunately *need* to use `TIMESTAMP` for TZ reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Better is use datatype `varchar(15)`.

Comment: Saving a number in the form of string is usually not a good pratice, for strings are slower in comparison and harder to perform calculation.

Comment: My vote goes to unsigned int-- but let's go down the rabbit hole. Why varchar and not char? It is a fixed length entry-- micro-optimization, but still...

Comment: timestamp is int, you should not use varchar for this kind of value

Answer (score 0):

You can do: `$date = \gmdate(\DATE_ISO8601);`.

Answer (score -1):

If I know the database is MySQL, I'll use the NOW() function like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
   (id, name, created_at) 
VALUES 
   (1, 'Gordon', NOW())
```

Comment: This would store the current timestamp only, not strictly what OP is asking for.