# Save time() as INTEGER timestamp in MySQL via PDO as phpMyAdmin says `timestamp` is number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

How can I send `timestamp`s as `integer` number to MySQL via PDO in PHP?
I dont like to send time as string, I want to send them as pure `integer` (as UNIX TIME).
[image: phpMyadmin help on TIMESTAMP format]

This is my code but it saves ZERO timestamp:

```
$sql = 'REPLACE INTO table_name (id,sent_timestamp) VALUES (:id,:sent_timestamp);';
$stmt =   $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':sent_timestamp',time(),PDO::PARAM_INT); // I define this column in phpMyadmin as TIMESTAMP type.

$stmt->execute();
```

`id` is unique and sql query is working but `timestamp` save as ZERO.
    I also replaced `time()` with arbitrary number like `123456` but it was also saved in DB as zero.

**UPDATED:** due to some more [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125947/what-is-the-data-type-for-unix-timestamp-mysql) and with thanks to `@Hanky Panky` ,
it is somthing confusing: why `phpMyadmin` says it stores `timestamp` as the numbers of seconds BUT we couldn't send `timestamp` as `integer`. 
Is there any reference to this item that we cant send in integer form?

Comment: @Hanky Panky , you marked my question as an exact duplicate but that question neither similar to my question nor comply my needs. Please remove this duplication mark.

Comment: It is. You just need to change your data type to an `INT(11)`  from `TIMESTAMP` as the format for `DATETIME/TIMESTAMP` is different and can not store an integer unix timestamp value. That is what is essentially discussed in that post. It has nothing to do with PDO. I explained that in an answer as well but i removed my answer when i saw a post discussing that already.

Comment: This change solves problem but I liked to see some refernece to documentation that says it is imposible,something that I couldn't find in that question. phpMyadmin says sql saves `timestamp` in numbers that i show in image ,so maybe rare way is there that we do not know about.

Comment: What reference would be needed to understand that a number can not be stored in a field that is of format `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS`? It is just like asking why you cant store `Hello` in a numeric field

Comment: So why phpMyadmin says `...store as the numbers of seconds....`? Not says `formatted time`.

Comment: Their wording is a confusing attempt at explaining that the date time stored in a `TIMESTAMP` field will always contain UTC time and not whatever the time is at the system right now. That is explained in the manual as well. *MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time.*

Comment: I like to change my question title. Maybe some one knows the real answer why they name in that way. Can I? I ask you as you have more experience in SO.

Comment: I have removed my vote as i do not want to discourage you from learning what you want to learn, but i still believe its just a misunderstanding of their terminology and nothing more. You can edit your question as you please

Comment: I updated my question ,thank you man.

Comment: It stores a timestamp __based__ on the number of seconds since 1970. It marks an absolute point in time. Like ... when we make a phone or Skype call at 9am based on a TIMESTAMP, no matter where you live in the world, we will come online at same time. With DATETIME we would be online hours before or after each other ... or in this case depending on your servers time and my servers timezone. The wording might be confusing was mentioned by Hanky Panky.

Comment: @HankyPanky, Finally I found the answer, long words short: we can send integers but only that integers in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS or YYMMDDHHMMSS format, only the numbers makes sense as a date not every integers like unix-time integers. You can see the full answer if you like.

Comment: @RyanVincent so I ONLY can save as int not `timestamp` at all. (for unix-time seconds)

Comment: Sorry, I confused you - no - Timestamp columns only accept DateTime formats. **They are DateTime fields** with 'timestamp' behaviour - that is 1) Stored as UTC. Display as the current server timezone. Maybe useful? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx

Comment: @TickTock Take a look at my answer. The answer to this is simple an clean. `time()` needs to be converted to `Y-m-d H:i:s` to store as a timestamp in mysql

Comment: You can use PHP `time()` in your PHP SQL queries but you have to use [FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp), FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) in your SQL query. These will convert the `unix epoch seconds` to UTC, using your server timezone.

Comment: imo, It maybe easier to just use `DateTime` columns and look after the time-zone stuff yourself? We do this all the time anyway? Use 'timestamp' for stuff the server needs to record - i.e. date of creation and update etc. The user time stuff - you look after yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with special THANKS to whom send answers but unfortunately non of them was the answer of my question.
Hopefully, after hours of searching I found the  answer:

We could send `TIMESTAMP` as an integer number. We could send it in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format and some other format. Invalid times interpret as ZEORs.
so this code works flawlessly:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':sent_timestamp',20160709120000,PDO::PARAM_INT); //2016-07-09-12:00:00
```

[MySQL Refernce says:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:

**As a number in either YYYYMMDDHHMMSS or YYMMDDHHMMSS format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905132800 and 830905132800 are interpreted as '1983-09-05 13:28:00'.**

> so due to this documentation it is **IMPOSSIBLE** to send unix-time
>   type integers-for example 14973898 (seconds after 1970-01-01-00-00) to
>   `TIMESTAMP`type fields **BUT** it is **POSSIBLE** to send integers in
>   YYYYMMDDHHMMSS and YYMMDDHHMMSS formats ( like 20160709120000 that
>   represents 2016-07-09-12:00:00)

**UPDATED**: my mistake on digits, it should 14-digit that i mistakely was wroten 12 digits by mistake.

Comment: I couldn't understand! why this answer should get Down vote?!

Comment: It seems to are missing the last bit seconds(`ss`). Other wise this is the correct answer! +1

Comment: My mistake,apologize.UPDATED

Comment: @RyanVincent you are true an i upvoted you formerley. I voted your second one up too

Answer (score 2):

A [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) in MySQL is a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]`.
The optional fraction part allows to store values to a precision of microseconds.
The allowed range for TIMESTAMP values is `1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000` to `2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999`.

In your query, you are trying to store an integer value into a TIMESTAMP field. For it to work properly, you must send a valid TIMESTAMP value:

```
$date = new Datetime('now');
$stmt->bindValue(':sent_timestamp', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STRING);
```

What phpmyadmin tries to explain is that TIMESTAMP values are **internally** stored as integers. But what matters to us, PHP programmers, is that TIMESTAMP values are seen as strings, as described above.

Remember that the authoritative source for MySQL is [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/), not explanations given by phpmyadmin.

Comment: So you say that it is IMPOSSIBLE to send directly `integer` numbers to `timstamp` type field due to `MySQL` documentation?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the answer using `FROM_UNIXTIME()`

[saving-timestamp-in-mysql-table-using-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632662/saving-timestamp-in-mysql-table-using-php)

Comment: Thank you but it is about how to send timestamp. my question is about how directly send integers to timestamp field.

Comment: why do you want to send it as an integer?

Comment: I really found the answer, you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks
[image: Create a table]

[image: Add a row]

[image: Check the result]

Comment: thanks , but its how we save ints ,You can see the real answer that I found after hours of frustrating research.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes it pays you in the long run to use shortcut practical tricks that solves your problem. Thanks. Hope you have now the work being done. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yes and i use inetegers for my field type.Albeit this question is about confusing words that phpMyadmin uses and `TIMESTAMP` integers!Thanks

Comment: @EpochGalaxy Next time please provide a proper answer with text explaining a bit instead of just posting pictures

Answer (score 0):

> Mysql timestamp requires the stamp format to be **'Y-m-d H:i:s'**.

You might be getting `0000` since to you telling PDO to store it as a INT. Remove the `PDO::PARAM_INT` from the bindValue statment

So, you would store `time()` as a timestamp like this:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':sent_timestamp',date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()));
```

Comment: +1 yes it is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format. i like to send direct integers that is only possible in that format. look to above answer

Comment: @TickTock How did you end up with this unfamiliar format `201607091200`?

Comment: If you look to my answer you completely would get the answer. 201607091200 is 2016-07-09-12:00. We can send integers but only that make sense a date. I do not why some one downvotes my answer? what is the problem with it. If you know please tell me.

Comment: @TickTock Your answer is right, but you are providing an incorrect value. You are supposed to be providing 14 digits instead of 12. You are missing the last `ss`

Comment: My Mistake ,UPDATED

Comment: @TickTock Please select an best answer so this question can be marked as answered

Comment: I like but I could not

Comment: @TickTock And why is that?

Comment: Question maker and the best answer is from same person.

Comment: @TickTock Yes, so mark your answer as the best answer

Comment: I will, StackOverflow says I can after two days( dont no why) I liked to some one else bring such an answer and get tick from me and save my time but  non of them can convince me about integers and so on. +1 for your hint about my mistake on digits.