# How to convert MySQL long timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my client's MySQL database, the following timestamp is saved and I am unable to convert it to date and time because it is invalid.

20211024090000

```
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', 20211024090000);
```

this code results in:

11/09/642431 23:20:00

But it should be 2021 year. I am sure that the timestamp is correct, I just can't figure out what type it is so I can convert it correctly.

Comment: It is not a timestamp, it is a mutilated datetime string. You should convert the values to a new column of datetime type, move these values to that column, formatted correctly, and drop this column. It is close to ISO format which would be something like `2021-10-24 T 09:00:00`. Could use https://regex101.com/r/fk7psH/1/ to break it apart.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving timestamp in mysql table using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632662/saving-timestamp-in-mysql-table-using-php)